# cannot insert or display image from express.js api in heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

i have an api created using express.js, it is contain upload and display image, it is word perfectly in localhost, and also in heroku local web, but in the same project in heroku cloud, everything also work except the image not displayed, i don't know if image inserted or not to folder, because i  cannot see the files or folder in heroku.... this is my code to upload image and it work in local heroku:

```
const filter = (req, file, cb)=>{
    if(file.mimetype == "image/jpg" || file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype == "image/png"){
        cb(null, true)
    }else{
        cb(null, false);
    }
}

const upload = multer({
    filter: filter
});
app.post('/service' ,upload.single('file'), checkAdminAuth, (req, res, next)=>{
    try {
        req.file != null ?
        sharp(req.file.buffer).resize(200, 200).toFile('upload/' 
        +req.file.originalname,
         (err, resizeImage) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
             //   fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path)
                console.log(resizeImage);
            }
            
        }) : ""
       // fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path)
       next()
        return res.status(201).json({
            message: 'success'
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});

app.use('/upload', express.static('upload'));
```

///////////////
this is the log come from heroku :

```
2020-08-03T12:27:53.175084+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-08-03T12:27:54.300490+00:00 app[web.1]: ::ffff:10.69.19.99 - - [03/Aug/2020:12:27:54 +0000] "GET /service/cat/5f27f0f6d3b2d900249dbcb7 HTTP/1.1" 200 329
2020-08-03T12:27:54.301859+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/service/cat/5f27f0f6d3b2d900249dbcb7" host=infinite-meadow-47540.herokuapp.com request_id=3fd0deaa-3237-4150-8e42-08aa484baebe fwd="185.95.207.81" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=32ms status=200 bytes=686 protocol=https
2020-08-03T12:27:55.404054+00:00 app[web.1]: ::ffff:10.155.88.71 - - [03/Aug/2020:12:27:55 +0000] "GET /service/cat/5f27f0f6d3b2d900249dbcb7 HTTP/1.1" 200 329
2020-08-03T12:27:55.404547+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/service/cat/5f27f0f6d3b2d900249dbcb7" host=infinite-meadow-47540.herokuapp.com request_id=b4c72174-4e32-4013-be61-f39cd3311b53 fwd="185.95.207.81" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=686 protocol=https
2020-08-03T12:27:56.443405+00:00 app[web.1]: ::ffff:10.45.252.73 - - [03/Aug/2020:12:27:56 +0000] "GET /service/cat/5f27f0f6d3b2d900249dbcb7 HTTP/1.1" 200 329
2020-08-03T12:27:56.446998+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/service/cat/5f27f0f6d3b2d900249dbcb7" host=infinite-meadow-47540.herokuapp.com request_id=2c77f41c-4bc4-4f52-b8ed-885d0c7e9544 fwd="185.95.207.81" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=686 protocol=https
2020-08-03T12:27:56.819064+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/upload/image_picker8301926133547768645.jpg" host=infinite-meadow-47540.herokuapp.com request_id=7d95912d-be4a-42a7-9b65-da69cd26a4b1 fwd="185.95.207.81" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=573 protocol=https
2020-08-03T12:27:56.822720+00:00 app[web.1]: ::ffff:10.30.127.176 - - [03/Aug/2020:12:27:56 +0000] "GET /upload/image_picker8301926133547768645.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 181
2020-08-03T12:28:00.626092+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/cat" host=infinite-meadow-47540.herokuapp.com request_id=e836406a-c878-4cde-a649-05757d0bdc5b fwd="185.95.207.81" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=848 protocol=https
2020-08-03T12:28:00.627757+00:00 app[web.1]: ::ffff:10.79.206.66 - - [03/Aug/2020:12:28:00 +0000] "GET /cat HTTP/1.1" 200 491
2020-08-03T12:28:00.642170+00:00 app[web.1]: ::ffff:10.9.247.118 - - [03/Aug/2020:12:28:00 +0000] "GET /cat HTTP/1.1" 200 491
2020-08-03T12:28:00.644944+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/cat" host=infinite-meadow-47540.herokuapp.com request_id=560a35d0-df32-463b-b8c1-eb4823afa3f8 fwd="185.95.207.81" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=848 protocol=https
2020-08-03T12:28:01.583557+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/cupload/139585975-e-learning-concept-with-blurred-city-abstract-lights-background.jpg" host=infinite-meadow-47540.herokuapp.com request_id=46562fa8-ac78-4f59-897e-0e44a2b6901e fwd="185.95.207.81" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=404 bytes=616 protocol=https
2020-08-03T12:28:01.585907+00:00 app[web.1]: ::ffff:10.63.145.147 - - [03/Aug/2020:12:28:01 +0000] "GET /cupload/139585975-e-learning-concept-with-blurred-city-abstract-lights-background.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 224
2020-08-03T12:28:06.990644+00:00 app[web.1]: ::ffff:10.45.155.176 - - [03/Aug/2020:12:28:06 +0000] "GET /cupload/139585975-e-learning-concept-with-blurred-city-abstract-lights-background.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 224
2020-08-03T12:28:06.998251+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/cupload/139585975-e-learning-concept-with-blurred-city-abstract-lights-background.jpg" host=infinite-meadow-47540.herokuapp.com request_id=b9e68097-d78c-4d5e-b9da-08a5a6779bdd fwd="185.95.207.81" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=616 protocol=https
2020-08-03T12:28:30.181544+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'upload/b858c17a46a29f9d7ddff5779df988dd'
2020-08-03T12:28:30.186011+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/service" host=infinite-meadow-47540.herokuapp.com request_id=66638e1f-8082-4624-ad3b-becae5428427 fwd="185.95.207.81" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10241ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
2020-08-03T12:29:21.876414+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'upload/8e8c7129133e0d2819bd1299d922767b'
2020-08-03T12:29:21.878333+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/service" host=infinite-meadow-47540.herokuapp.com request_id=2b6a2985-ceb8-4774-8000-4b320ef162f4 fwd="185.95.207.81" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11393ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
2020-08-03T13:01:53.096720+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2020-08-03T13:01:53.098427+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-08-03T13:01:54.003136+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-08-03T13:01:54.083729+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-08-03T13:43:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user osama.cs@cihanuniversity.edu.iq
2020-08-03T13:43:38.449759+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 40ec5723 by user osama.cs@cihanuniversity.edu.iq
2020-08-03T13:43:38.449759+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user osama.cs@cihanuniversity.edu.iq
2020-08-03T13:43:38.613016+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2020-08-03T13:43:41.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

Answer (score 2):

The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many container based systems, such as Docker, operate.

In addition, under normal operations dynos will restart every day in a process known as "Cycling".

These two facts mean that the filesystem on Heroku is not suitable for persistent storage of data. In cases where you need to store data we recommend using a database addon such as Postgres (for data) or a dedicated file storage service such as AWS S3 (for static files). If you don't want to set up an account with AWS to create an S3 bucket we also have addons here that handle storage and processing of static assets https://elements.heroku.com/addons

Take a read of https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: so, when can i test my application with full feature for free?

Comment: I think you can use Cloudinary. It's Starter plan(10GB storage) is free.
https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cloudinary

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudinary#using-with-node-js